# if $2a+3b \geq 12m+1$, then either $a \geq 3m+1$ or $b \geq 2m+1$

Tags: inequality, integers

Not sure how to go about proving this. So far I've declared the contrapositive but can't seem to get further...

Let $a,\ b$ and $m$ be integers. Prove that if $2a+3b \geq 12m+1$, then $a \geq 3m+1$ or $b \geq 2m+1$

So I've written: If $a<3m+1$ and $b<2m+1$, then $2a+3b<12m+1$, but cannot seem to make any more progress.

Comment: What do you mean you've "declared the contrapositive"?

Comment: @ADH I recommend you edit your question to include your statement of the contrapositive. This will show your effort thus far, as well as help identify anything that may have gone wrong. As it is, your question doesn't demonstrate any work on your part and is less likely to get a quality response.

Comment: @BaronVT good point, just added it

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**.  Note that we are talking about **integers**.  So the inequalities
$$a<3m+1\ ,\quad b<2m+1$$
imply
$$a\le 3m\ ,\quad b\le2m\ .$$
Can you now show that the statement $2a+3b\ge12m+1$ is false?

Comment: Didn't catch that property about the integers, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The contrapositive is: If $a<3m+1$ and $b<2m+1$, then $2a+3b<12m+1$.

Just compute:

$\quad a<3m+1$ implies $2a<6m+2$.

$\quad b<2m+1$ implies $3b<6m+3$.

These imply $2a+3b<12m+5$ — oops, not quite what we need.

Since we're dealing with integers, we have $x < y$ implies $x \le y-1$. Let's try again:

$\quad a<3m+1$ implies $a\le 3m$ and so $2a\le 6m$.

$\quad b<2m+1$ implies $b \le 2m$ and so $3b\le6m$.

Now, these imply $2a+3b\le 12m < 12m+1$.